# How to check in code if CPU supports hardware acceleration on C#?

Tags: c#, directx, direct3d, hardware-acceleration

I am building a program which uses a `Direct3D` object, `using Direct3D = Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D`, to render a live stream. I tested it on a `Windows 7` machine and the issue is that the CPU does not support `Hardware Acceleration`. To run the program, I changed the flag when I create the `Direct3D` object to `Direct3D.CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing`, which is fine. I would like to know if there is any way to check if the CPU supports `Hardware Acceleration`. If so, use `Direct3D.CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProcessing` and if not, use `software`. My program will run a different machines, so it would be better this way than to build two programs. The program is written in `C#` but if you know how to do it in other languages I would appreciate it and I will try to translate in `C#`.

Comment: Be aware that ``Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D`` is part of the *Managed DirectX 1.1* assemblies. It's deprecated and only installed by the end-of-life [legacy DirectX SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-) and/or [deprecated DXSETUP](https://aka.ms/dxsetup). Instead, you should look at using [SlimDX](https://github.com/SlimDX/slimdx) or [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) managed assemblies. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-and-net/).

Comment: CPU never supports hardware acceleration. It is GPU that supports it.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn that's why I got confused. I've read about `GetDeviceCaps` but `Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D` does not have it as a property. I've installed `SharpDX` as a `NuGet` package and works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a more direct route in C# but in [C++][1] you can check with:

```
HRESULT GetDeviceCaps(
  UINT       Adapter,
  D3DDEVTYPE DeviceType,
  D3DCAPS9   *pCaps
);
```

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/selecting-a-device

Comment: I was looking for `GetDeviceCaps` but I didn't know it is not supported on `DirectX`.  I've installed `SharpDX` as a `NuGet` package and works fine. Thanks!